# Profile Tomcat instance running on Redhat

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, profiling, profiler

I found the Tomcat keep occupying CPU (constantly > 40% from top)  on a redhat system. I want to check which methods eats the CPU. Does anyone know how to profile it?

It's hard to connect VisualVM to the remote server because of the security reason. Is there any command line tools for me to request the tomcat JVM instance to dump something and get it back to my local for profiling analysis?

thanks,
Green

Comment: Do you have a "real" profiler? Usually, you can launch a JVM with a profiling agent and then connect to that with a little more ease than trying to connect using the "Java Agent" protocol. Remote profiling is always a pain...

Comment: Can you recommend a "real" profiler?

Comment: I have used Borland OptimizeIt (long ago) and YourKit (currently). I like YourKit but haven't used it extensively, and usually not remotely. *Full disclosure: YourKit gives me a free license as an ASF committer.*

Answer (score 0):

With [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/index.html), you would extract the JProfiler .tar.gz file on the remote side, then run the command line exedutables `bin/jpenable` to load the profiling agent, then `bin/jpcontroller` to record data and save a snapshot.

Saved snapshots can be transferred to your desktop machine and opened with the JProfiler GUI.

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler

Comment: thx. looks good. would be greater if it's an open source product ;-)